# Not able to remotely connect from Visual VM

Tags: cloud-foundry, visualvm

I have one application deployed in one of the CF cloud providers.

My application is on https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#v4.6

I am following this post to connect visual vm to the java app
https://fabianlee.org/2017/12/09/cloudfoundry-enabling-java-jmx-rmi-access-for-remote-containers/

I enabled the JMX connection.

But when i add the JMX connection in visual vm as localhost:5000

I get "Cannot connect to localhost:5000 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:5000/jmxrmi"

I have also tried enabling remote debugging in my application through JDWP option and connecting as a remote host in visual vm but that also results " cannot connect" error.

Am i missing anything here ?

Has anyone connected memory profilers to cf containers ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

JMX needed to be enabled in the container by using this command and that enabled JMX connection from visualvm

`cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_JMX '{ enabled: true }'`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the SSH tunneling is not working for you.

First thing you might want to try is the ssh into the application container using `cf ssh <application_name>`

Once you are in the container run `netstat -lntu` to find the debugging port `8000` is open or not. If its open then,exit the ssh console, tunnel to the  application using  `cf ssh -N -T -L <LOCAL_PORT>:localhost:<REMOTE_PORT> <APPLICATION_NAME>`, and try connecting back to localhost:8000

If the debugging port is not open then set the `JBP_CONFIG_DEBUG '{enabled: true}'` variable and restart the application.

Also the default debug port is 8000 and not 5000 so if you want to connect to port 5000 your ssh command should be `cf ssh -N -T -L 5000:localhost:8000<APPLICATION_NAME>`

Comment: thanks Shiva for the reply..i checked that remote port is opened and followed the steps mentioned by you...but getting the same error